# How to repeat certain lines conditionally in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

I have an array like:
`arr=[[1,2,3,4,'a,b,c,d'],[5,6,7,8,'e,f,g,h']]`

I want to be:
`arr=[[1,2,3,4,'a'],[1,2,3,4,'b'],[1,2,3,4,'c'],[1,2,3,4,'d'],[5,6,7,8,'e'],[5,6,7,8,'f'],[5,6,7,8,'g'],[5,6,7,8,'h']]`

can somebody helps to gives me a suggestion? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through the string (last element in list) and append the answer onto everything but the last element

```
new_arr = [[li[:-1]+[letter] for letter in li[-1].split(',')] for li in arr]
# Flatten
out = [item for sublist in new_arr for item in sublist]
```

Comment: thank you very much. This answer is very helpful to me. Then I found another way to solved it. share ^0^.
`arr=pd.DataFrame(arr)

arr.columns=['a','b','c','d','e']

arr.assign(e=arr.e.str.split(',')).explode('e')`